# How to set trailingAnchor.constraint for imageView inside scrollview through loop swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

This is how I am showing my image views inside the scroll view through for loop:

```
func addPageController() {
        let imgArray = ["AquariumBG", "PaludariumBG", "TerrariumBG"]

        let scrollContentViewWidthAnchor = scrollContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerScrollView.widthAnchor, constant:0)
        scrollContentViewWidthAnchor.isActive = true

        for (index, item) in imgArray.enumerated() {
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: item)
            let xPos = CGFloat(index) * UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

            scrollContentView.addSubview(imgView)
            scrollContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            scrollContentViewWidthAnchor.constant = xPos

            scrollContentView.setNeedsLayout()
            scrollContentView.layoutIfNeeded()

            imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerScrollView.frame.size.width).isActive = true
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: xPos).isActive = true
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerScrollView.frame.size.width).isActive = true

            imgView.setNeedsLayout()
            imgView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

And this is the output:

[image]

It is showing perfectly. Now If I swipe the header down to the screen (Cause it is stretchy header) the second image also shows with the first image like this:

[image]

The reason for this is because the image views have no `trailingAnchor.constraint`. So my question is, is it possible to set trailing anchor with the image views inside a loop, when the next image view hasn't created yet? If so how? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My Storyboard:

[image]

**[SAMPLE PROJECT LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgriju6j5cxnz8p/TableViewWithStretchyHeaderEffect.zip?dl=0)**

Comment: Can you not set it via section insets and spacing on your layout instead? This is the reason those exist

Comment: @Pancho Thanks for commenting. Can you elaborate that, please?

Comment: Sorry I only red your title briefly and missed the part that you're using `UIScrollView` in which case you would need to set a constraints. I was thinking you're using `UICollectionView` in which case my comment above would make sense.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are doing... Do you have a scroll view above the "Discount Price" label? When you "swipe down" are you changing the height constraint of that scroll view?

Comment: Ok, Wait for a while let me update my question with some more graphics.

Comment: @DonMag I have updated my question with the storyboard image. Yes, the scroll view is placed inside a table `tableHeaderView` (Which is stretchy). So the hierarchy is `tableHeaderView` > `scrollView` > `scrollContentView` > `imageView`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

While I would still suggest using a stack view for the imageViews, that wasn't the problem.

After reviewing your Sample Project, you can fix the issue with one line of code.

Inside your loop:

```
    for (index, item) in imgArray.enumerated() {
        let imgView = UIImageView()

        // add this line
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true

        // continue with what you had...
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        // etc...
    }
```

**End of Edit**

---

I would suggest putting a `UIStackView` in your scroll view, then adding your image views as arranged subviews.

Here is an example with a scroll view in a "normal" view, but it will translate pretty much directly to using it in a table header view:

```
class ScrollHeaderTestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var theScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addPageController()
    }

    func addPageController() -> Void {

        let imgArray = ["AquariumBG", "PaludariumBG", "TerrariumBG"]

        imgArray.forEach { imgName in
            if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
                let v = UIImageView()
                v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                v.image = img
                theStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And here is how it is setup in storyboard:

[image]

The scroll view is constrained top / leading / trailing, with a height of 150

The stack view is constrained all 4 sides to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide, with the Height equal to the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide height. The width is constrained to 200 (just a random number I picked that is narrower than the view), but that constraint has a `Priority of 250` -- this allows it to auto-expand as you add arranged subviews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me give a try. And I have added a sample project link with the question. You can take have a look if you want.

Comment: OMG! I was seeking for this. Thanks a lot, man. You save my time again. :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use collectionView with pagination as true. And then a you can change the constraints dynamically in the code in respect to the scrolled content-offset to give sticky effect.

```
                     or
```

* And in this code Trailing constraint is missing is not the only reason behind it. You can give you image a width constraint. You should give leading constraint of a image to the trailing constraint of image previous to it and the last image will be having its trailing as the container view

Try this

```
for (index, item) in imgArray.enumerated() {
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: item)
            var leadingView  = scrollContentView
            //get the view previous view to it
            if index > 0 {
                leadingView = scrollContentView.subviews[index - 1]
            }
            scrollContentView.addSubview(imgView)
            imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerScrollView.frame.size.width).isActive = true
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            //if this is last image set the trailingAnchor
            if index == imgArray.count - 1 {
                imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }
```